# What are the good book to understand economics?

Tags: economics

I am currently studying managerial economics by W. Bruce Allen. The book is good. Are there any good book with quizzes , that makes economics sweeter? Books that relate to real world facts and figure would be better.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about economics, not mathematical/computational finance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good introductory book with a lot of data and statistics provided is: "Macroeconomics: Understanding the Global Economy" by David Miles and Andrew Scott. You can find the link to the book here:

[Macroeconomics - Miles/Scott](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119995728)

It uses a lot of real world examples to relate economic concepts with real data and explain observed economic phenomena.

If you are interested also in Microeconomics I would recommend Mankiw and Krugman which you can find here:

[Microeconomics - Krugman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1429283424)

[Microeconomics - Mankiw](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0538453044)